# Android Bluetooth Altbeacon Calibration

Tags: android, bluetooth, altbeacon

guys
I'm using Altbeacon Android Library to do some Bluetooth app for demo. It provides with a getDistance() method that I can use to get distance between my phone and external Bluetooth device with Altbeacon protocol uploaded. However, as the devices are different, I think the distance might vary with a large error (I get 0.05m when I'm at 1m away, so on and so forth). This makes me think that if we do some calibration work for the getDistance() method will be useful. Is there any way of doing this? (Currently I have no idea how to modify the getDistance method, maybe @override it? Not very sure)
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any calibration functionality in the library. However, you can change distance calculation by implementing your own `DistanceCalculator`.

The default distance calculator is `ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator` and it set in the `BeaconService`s `onCreate` method (check [this](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/service/BeaconService.java#L214-L215)). So, simply creating your own version of the `DistanceCalculator` and set it after `BeaconService` is created can do what you want;

```
// after beacon service is created
DistanceCalculator customCalculator = ...;
Beacon.setDistanceCalculator(customCalculator);
```

However, you should now that device is also causes variation;

> Each model may have a different Bluetooth chipset and antenna, and therefore may receive a different signal level when in the same position relative to a beacon. In order to address this, the library uses a different formula for calculating distance for different Android device models. Because not all devices have custom formulas built into the library, the library will fall back to the default device calculation for the Nexus 5 if no matching formula is found.

For more information about distance calculation, please visit [AltBeacon - Distance Calculations](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/distance-calculations.html) page. This page also explains how distance calculation works as well as how you can contribute to enhance the library for device variation.

By the way, you can also check `CurveFittedDistanceCalculator` but this one requires you to give device specific coefficients (explained in [this page](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/distance-calculations.html)). For more info about this, check its [source code](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/distance/CurveFittedDistanceCalculator.java).

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. So I just need to input the formula in "DistanceCalculator customCalculator" right? Besides, do you how to detect some specific beacons? Now I can use Beacon.iterator().next() to get beacons, can I extract each beacon separately and store them in different variables instead of one? Many thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to create your own calculator and set it to `Beacon` but please read the source code of original calculator before writing your own. It will help you to understand. What do you mean by specific beacons? Do you mean two different kind of beacon (like iBeacon, Eddystone) or with specific ids like UUID, Major, Minor in iBeacon? In either case you can create a `Region` for specific cases. Then those specific `Beacon`s will be reported separately.

Comment: Actually I mean the UUID things, but it's very helpful to hear your suggestions about iBeacon and Eddystone. So in your way, if I wanna modify the code, like the reference app provided by Altbeacon, I will need to update the region information first, then the service method: "didEnterRegion" will help to give different response to it?

Comment: But another problem is, I'm not sure if modifying this will change the monitoring activity, like it will still get the information from all beacons. Though it might give me different responses, it seems I still need to modify the monitoring activity to get info from specific beacons only. Can I just extract information from "didEnterRegion" this kind of method? Thanks~